# Invert text color to color of bg on hover

Tags: html, css, background-color, mousehover

Is there a way to create rule which will allow me to on hover change link's text color to background color and background color to old text color?

Here is the example of code that i don't like ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/0w2oL5nm/)):

```
a {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #dea12c;
    color: #dea12c;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: #dea12c;
    color: white;
}
```

Suppose i wanna use five, seven or twenty colors! It will be really booring to create a :hover rule for EVERY element, it would be much more easy, fast and elegant to create only one :hover rule for all elements at once. It should look like this:

```
a.red {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
}
a.blue {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    color: blue;
}
...
a:hover {
    background-color: initialBorderColor;
    color: white;
}
```

It is veeery easy to achieve this with JS but i want only CSS+HTML solution.

Comment: Why do you want to use so many colors?

Comment: Nop not with regular CSS

Comment: Colors will be used to reflect the kind of link: red is to delete some entry, green is to create maybe, black is to... dunno, it's just an idea)

Comment: It cannot be done, the best thing you could do is use a:hover,mydiv:hover,somelement:hover { ...styles}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Live Demo

```
<a>MOVE YOUR CURSOR HERE!</a> 

<a>MOVE YOUR CURSOR HERE!</a>
```

**Style**

```
a:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #FFF000;
    border: 2px solid #000FFF;
    color: #000FFF;
}
a:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #0077CC;
    border: 2px solid #FF8833;
    color: #FF8833;
}
a:hover {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

this tool can generate inverted color pairs : [TOOL](http://www.colortools.net/color_complementary.html)

---

update(because of comments ):

## Demo

I think there are no way to read anther element style using pure css

```
<a class="delete">Delete</a> 
<a class="create">Create</a>
<a class="black">Black</a>
```

**style**

```
.delete{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #F00;
    color: #F00;    
}
.create{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #0F0;
    color: #0F0;    
}
.black{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #000;    
}
.delete:hover{
    background-color: #F00;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;   
}
.create:hover{
    background-color: #0F0;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;    
}
.black:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;    
}
```

Comment: Only problem is: OP asked about white background with different colors, not just inverted colors.

Comment: I was talking about one :hover rule for all kinds of links, but thanks anyways)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using the CSS preprocessor like SASS, which helps to assign the values dynamically.

```
$font-color:#dea12c;
$background-color:white;

a {
    background-color: $background-color;
    border: 2px solid #dea12c;
    color: $font-color;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: $font-color;
    color: $background-color;
}
```

Comment: Your example generates a very simple rule, that could be easily achieved by pure CSS. Can you provide an example that generates OP's second example?